# Is there a way to do a "git commit --amend" that automatically uses the old commit message instead of prompting us to edit the old one?

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip the commit message step when I run git commit --amend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307417/can-i-skip-the-commit-message-step-when-i-run-git-commit-amend)

Is there a way to do a `git commit --amend` that automatically uses the old commit message instead of prompting us to edit the old one?

I know I just need to type in `<ESC>:q` but if there was some other argument I'd pass in the git commit, I'd prefer it that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure:

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Comment: I recommend making this into an alias, so then you can just go `git amend` (or more often, `git amend -a`. Obviously you could include the -a in the alias if you want)