# git commit --amend without asking for message

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

From time to time I find myself *commit-amending* using the same message.

Typically, I do:

1. Add my changes to staging area.
2. Do `git commit --amend`.
3. Wait for the text editor to open.
4. Save and close it (without changing the message).

There is anyway to tell git that I don't want to change the commit message (skipping the step of opening my text editor and saving the message)? Like:

1. Add my changes to staging area.
2. Tell git to amend my staging area to the last commit without asking me for another message.

---

I know I can avoid git firing up my text editor by doing `git commit --amend -m "<message>"`. But this way I would have to retype the message.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Try `git commit --amend --no-edit`.

Comment: Note: The --no-edit flag was added in Git 1.7.9: https://github.com/git/git/blob/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt#L45-L47

The other answer will work for previous Git versions

Answer (score 19):

This will amend the latest commit, using that same message, in one command:

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Comment: This option works perfectly on centOS 6.7 (final). because --no-edit option is not yet avaiable in that platform, through a standard git yum install. NOTE: git version 1.7.1

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365442/710377:
This option was added in Git 1.7.9.