# How to inhibit pop-up after git --amend

Tags: git

I'm a using git-bash on windows. Is it possible to inhibit the popup that appears after I run:

```
'git commit -a --amend'
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [git commit --amend --use-existing-message? (no editor interaction)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237071/git-commit-amend-use-existing-message-no-editor-interaction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ([`git commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)) a:

```
git commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

That avoid editing the commit message when amending the content of a git commit.

> Use the selected commit message without launching an editor

---

The other option would be `--reuse-message=<commit>` if you wanted to reuse the the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) of a commit.
In your case: `HEAD` (or `@`)

```
git commit -a --amend -C @
```

Answer (score 0):

Since git 1.7.9 version you can use `git commit --amend --no-edit` to ignore the message popup.